# Is there a way to properly redirect or rewrite vistors in my drupal 8 website to a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, drupal-8

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysitedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

I'm currently using CPanel and CPanel does not allow you to set a new Document Root. So have my drupal files in my CPanel "public_html" directory with the composer.json files etc..and web directory that has all the Drupal related files. I am trying to get the site vistors to rewrite or redirect to www.mysitedomain.com/web for subsequent pages.. I tried the code below but does not seem to work.. Am i missing something?

To be specific.... **I need the site to 1. load www.mysitedomain.com/web when www.mysitedomain.com is requested. 2. And ensure /web is is front of every subsequent request  page request within the site (ie. www.mysitedomain.com/web/products should load instead of www.mysitedomain.com/products)**

Comment: Check if this my answer helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363570/4842735

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but I think you need something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

What it does: If the URL does not resolve to a file or directory in the present directory, put index.php in front of it.

I'd assume your index.php would then include the Drupal framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response @p2000. I tried your solution but could not load the pages properly. To be specific.... I need the site to 1. load www.mysitedomain.com/web when www.mysitedomain.com is requested. 2. And ensure /web is is front of every subsequent request  page request within the site (ie. www.mysitedomain.com/web/products should load instead of www.mysitedomain.com/products)

Comment: Ok, in that case, replace "index.php" with "web" and you can remove the two RewriteCond lines. Let me know if that does what you need, and I will update the answer.