# Drupal redirect to web folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to configure redirects on a drupal site using apache web server. I'm trying to implement this https://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/remove-web-part-composer-based-drupal-site but I cannot seem to get it working. I have several drupal sites running in `/var/www/html/drupal`. My drupal configuration in my httpd.conf files are

```
- name: create drupal httpd conf
    copy:
      content: |
               <VirtualHost *:80>
                 ServerName qsd
                 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
                 <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymlinks
                    AllowOverride All
                 </Directory>
               </VirtualHost>
      dest: /etc/httpd/conf.d/drupal.conf
```

and

```
- name: allow override /var/www/html
    copy:
      content: |
                <Directory "/var/www/html">
                  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride All
                  Require all granted
                </Directory>
      dest: /etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf
```

I've added

```
if ( isset($GLOBALS['request']) && '/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME') ) {
    $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

to my settings.php.

Now I'm trying to get my `.htaccess` files correct for my drupal app which is in `/var/www/html/drupal/app`. In `/var/www/html/drupal/app/.htaccess` I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect to the subdirectory because that's where Drupal is installed
RewriteBase /app
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In `var/www/html/drupal/app/web/.htaccess` I have

```
RewriteBase /web
```

When I visit https://example.com/app I get redirected to my OIDC provider but the `redirect_uri` is missing the `/app`. And when I visit https://example.com/app/user/login I get a 404, but prior to adding `.htaccess` https://example.com/app/web/user/login was working. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal` be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/web` if your site is within the web directory?

Comment: there's multiple sites, this site is in `/var/www/html/drupal/app`, there's another in `/var/www/html/drupal/app2`, etc. Is this the correct way to configure the document root?

Comment: "there's multiple sites", Do you mean different URLs for each? You would have a virtual host for each of them each with different document roots I think

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change `var/www/html/drupal/app/web/.htaccess` to

```
RewriteBase /app/web
```

and settings.php to

```
if ( isset($GLOBALS['request']) && '/app/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME') ) {
    $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/app/index.php');
}
```

But I think creating a virtual host for each site would allow the original configuration to work as @2pha suggested

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps for access drupal from sub-folder with or without www([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). This I have tried and tested in cpanel.

- /public_html/ edit the .htaccess and add below lines:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>  RewriteEngine on
>  RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

- /web folder we have to edit .htaccess and update below line

> RewriteBase /web

- In settings.php please update the below line

```
     if ( isset($GLOBALS['request']) && '/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME') ) {
         $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php'); 
     }
```

- In cpanel add the **CNAME** in your [zone editor](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/zone-editor/) or https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-domain-features/using-the-cpanel-zone-editor/ for your domain to access **with or without www([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))**.
  Example - Your doamin is example.com so you have to add a CNAME like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

I avoid tampering with the server settings or writing redirects when installing Drupal 8+. I make what is called a 'modified install'. This enables me to stop project initiation mid way to tell Composer where to install Drupal, i.e. to tell Composer what my web-root is, so it doesn't go ahead to assume it is 'web/'.

If you are using shared hosting then most likely your web-root will be 'public_html' and if you don't make a modified install, Composer will assume it is 'web/'. So I would make a modified install and tell Composer not to install Drupal inside 'web' but rather to install inside 'public_html'.

I wrote the steps on a blog post, [How to install Drupal 9 with Composer on Cpanel](https://www.skillmaticace.com/blog/how-install-drupal-9-composer-cpanel). This post is about installing on a cPanel account but the process demonstrates making a modified install, and same principle can be used to install locally or in any folder structure.