# How to adjust htaccess for Drupal9 so website opens as www.mydomain.com from a subfolder of the root not root

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a question about .htaccess for Drupal 9. I created the page on localhost using a composer and copied a locally prepared instance of Drupal9 to the web hosting, which runs from a subfolder (www / web / index.php).
To guarantee opening from [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) on the web hosting, I created a new .htaccess with these variables in the root folder www :
'''

> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteRule ^$ web/index.php [L]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -f
> RewriteRule .* web/$0 [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule .* web/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://something.ws/$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
> RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
> '''
> With this I was able to open a domain from [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com). The home page is loading So it's OK in this part.

The problem occurs when I want to open a web page from the home page or log in. After a shredding for a while, it throws up the error ‘The page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. ’ The following is repeated in the address bar:
'''

> / user / login? Q = user / login & q = user / login & q = user / login
> '''

Similar problem occurred with other links. I want to ask:
How to fix this usinh .htaccess

1. How to prevent this creation of loops in htaccess
2. I created a new htaccess in root www. Other htaccess under the web and in sites / default are unchanged
3. Is it necessary to make any change in the other htaccess /web, sites / defaults?
   I also asked the provider if it is possible to change the hosting address, unfortunately it only goes through htaccess.
   Thank you for any comments or advice

Comment: For the solution please check my comment [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536992/drupal-redirect-to-web-folder/77742174#77742174](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536992/drupal-redirect-to-web-folder/77742174#77742174)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you hit https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/3096948 ?
At least that's the cause for the exact same loop in my case.

In short, the "redirect" module - if you use it - seems to be buggy.
Try disabling `route_normalizer_enabled` in its config, either by changing the variable in the `redirect.settings.yml` config file and using drush to import the changed config (`drush cim`), or by issuing

```
drush cset redirect.settings route_normalizer_enabled 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already solved it bz adjusting htaccess in root, web and file directory

Comment: @robil123 Can you please share the solution which you did in htaccess in root, web directory?